# Flex - Change Browser

Tags: apache-flex, browser

How do I change which browser Flex uses when I run my project?

Answer (score 8):

It's under Flex Builder > Preferences > General > Web Browser

Answer (score 2):

Or if you're using Eclipse, it's Window > Preferences > General > Web Browser

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Internet Explorer from my Windows 7 machine and set Google Chrome as the default browser. Adobe Flex 3 exhibits the following behavior:

Use internal Web Browser -> Flex tries to launch iexplore.exe, which fails.

Use external Web Browser, Default system Web Browser -> Flex tries to launch iexplore.exe, which fails. (Note that the default browser is Chrome)

Use external Web Browser, Chrome (manually added) -> Flex launches Chrome correctly.

So if anyone had the same problem, just add Chrome manually. It is located in `C:\Users\(user)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`.